# Change ASP.NET UI alignments etc

Tags: asp.net, css, user-interface

I was given a website in ASP.NET and I have to change the look of it by adjusting and fixing the div tags etc. What is the easiest way I can learn how to do this efficiently? The previous user was making use of tables to set the images etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign the complete website or just change some setting keeping table layout. 
table is good for displaying for rows and column data.

but in any case you need to use CSS **Cascading Style Sheets** www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Its easy to work in asp.net, just create masterpage and it will help you manage your design. and give a same look to all pages.

I hope it help you.